# Why ul gets triggered when I click on li?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, live

I have this html:

```
 <ul class='loc-list'>  
     <li id="where_7" class="cont-list">North America
         <ul>
            <li id="contry_114" class="contry-list">canada</li>
            <li id="contry_115" class="contry-list">mexico</li>
            <li id="contry_117" class="contry-list">united states</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Now I have written two jquery functions onclick of list as:

**1<sup>st</sup>:**

```
$(".cont-list").on("click", function(event){
     alert("clicked on continent's list"); // working fine
 };
```

**2<sup>nd</sup>:**

```
$(".contry-list").on("click", function(event){
     alert("clicked on country's list");  // not working!
 };
```

Here when I click on **cont-list** it get called ones as it should , but in the **2<sup>nd</sup>** function it is **not** getting called instead it **1<sup>st</sup>** function get called!

Is is because of it being an inner list? If so, then how to deal with this so that it will be called only when clicked on that list only?

[**The demo is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sandip007/nuCPv)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Event Bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). Learn about it.

Comment: This is because of DOM event bubbling. edit: just saw the above, correct comment.

Comment: Also your code runs, you have an issue somewhere else.

Comment: jQuery can only bind event handlers to elements that exist. Please read the [`.on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), specifically [the section about *Direct and delegated events*](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because events bubble up, you can use `stopPropagation` method of the `event` object:

```
$(".contry-list").on("click", function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     alert("clicked on country's list");  
});
```

If you are generating the `li` elements dynamically you should delegate the event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.coutry-list', function(){
   console.log('li element is clicked');
})
```

Comment: @sandip Do you generate the `li` elements dynamically?

Comment: Yeah the inner list (the country list) is generated dyanamicaly

Comment: @undefined thnks for you reply but it is not working for dynamic list!

Comment: @sandip The parent element should be static, try with `document` object one of the  static parents of the `li` elements instead.

Comment: @undefined I tested this by making changes in the demo given by Will.i.am but the 2nd function is not getting called!

Comment: @FelixKling I am sorry , May be I should just read event bubbling & try

Comment: @undefined  here is the  demo link :http://jsfiddle.net/Sandip007/nuCPv/ see here when I click on dynamic list of countries the 1st function get called!

Comment: @sandip: You didn't even incorporate undefined's suggested solution.

Comment: @FelixKling ya that's because when I did that the 1st function also not getting called!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".contry-list").on("click", function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     alert("clicked on country's list");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$(".contry-list").on("click", function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     alert("clicked on country's list");
});
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/pT4ca/)

Answer (score 0):

A fix in jQuery would be:

```
$(".contry-list").on("click", function(event){
     alert("clicked on country's list");  // not working!
    return false; 
});
```

But as epascarello points out, you should learn about DOM event bubbling (and capturing) to understand it.