# How to get the nested ul li text in jquery onclick

Tags: jquery

How to get the text in nested ul li text in `onclick` in jquery
my code is as follows,

When I click the li I need to get the current li text,

```js
$('.selectRow li').on('click', function() {
  var textSelected = $(this).text();
  console.log(textSelected)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="selectRow">
  <li>test-1</li>
  <li>test-2</li>
  <li>test-3
    <ul>
      <li>test-3.1</li>
      <li>test-3.2</li>
      <li>test-3.3</li>
      <li>test-3.4</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>test-4</li>
    <li>test-5</li>
    <li>test-6
      <ul>
        <li>test-6.1</li>
        <li>test-6.2</li>
        <li>test-6.3</li>
        <li>test-6.4</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

I getting the current li text onclick, but if li click the submenu li I am getting all parent li text and submenu li text also. Can anyone tell me the solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen sorry i am not getting u can pls update my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't get the solution I found for you, I've made this example for you:

```
$('.selectRow li').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target == e.currentTarget) {

    var textSelected = $(this)
      .clone() //clone the element
      .children() //select all the children
      .remove() //remove all the children
      .end() //again go back to selected element
      .text()
      .trim();
    console.log(textSelected);
  }
})
```

This will only return the text of the clicked `li`

**Demo**

```js
$('.selectRow li').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target == e.currentTarget) {

    var textSelected = $(this)
      .clone() //clone the element
      .children() //select all the children
      .remove() //remove all the children
      .end() //again go back to selected element
      .text()
      .trim();
    console.log(textSelected);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="selectRow">
  <li>test-1</li>
  <li>test-2</li>
  <li>test-3
    <ul>
      <li>test-3.1</li>
      <li>test-3.2</li>
      <li>test-3.3</li>
      <li>test-3.4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>test-4</li>
  <li>test-5</li>
  <li>test-6
    <ul>
      <li>test-6.1</li>
      <li>test-6.2</li>
      <li>test-6.3</li>
      <li>test-6.4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @techie18 No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution 
You can use `stopPropagation` method of the event object:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.selectRow li', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   console.log('li element is clicked');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="selectRow">
  <li>test-1</li>
  <li>test-2</li>
  <li>test-3
    <ul>
      <li>test-3.1</li>
      <li>test-3.2</li>
      <li>test-3.3</li>
      <li>test-3.4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li>test-4</li>
    <li>test-5</li>
    <li>test-6
      <ul>
        <li>test-6.1</li>
        <li>test-6.2</li>
        <li>test-6.3</li>
        <li>test-6.4</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

You will find the answer also here
[Why ul gets triggered when I click on li?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137332/why-ul-gets-triggered-when-i-click-on-li)